# Publishing with IIS: Server DNS could not be found

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns

I'm trying to publish my project using IIS

I was able to publish it via Visual Studio:

```
La aplicación web se publicó correctamente file:///D:/www/plataformafantasy.com

========== Compilar: 1 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
========== Publicación: 1 procesados, 0 no procesados, 0 omitidos ==========
```

[image]

But when I try to access the page: http://www.plataformafantasy.com/

I get the error:

> The DNS address of the www.plataformafantasy.com server could not be found.

I basically followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwbKquNBNgQ

And to counter this error I edited the **hosts** file, following this answer:

[server DNS address could not be found - iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033434/server-dns-address-could-not-be-found-iis)

```
127.0.0.1 plataformafantasy.com
0.0.0.1 mssplus.mcafee.com (This was already in the file)
```

Still not working.

Also, looking into my IIS I noticed that only one application is running:

[image]

I'm very new to this, I haven't configured anything besides the IIS. What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

**Update: Extra info**

[image]

[image]

*Connect as:*

[image]

Comment: You need to add a web site. See documentation https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I believe I have added it. See updated post. Added a picture at the begining of the question :)

Comment: It looks like the physical path should be <<your path>>`\wwwroot`. Also set permissions to the account which runs application pool of the site.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Alex. (1) Updated the path - Image updated (2) Added picture of how the connection is set for the user: Applicaiton user - pass-through authentication

Comment: Seems like the user (whichever might be) don't have access to the folder. I'll try to look deeper into this.